# Oracle: Java Stored Procedures limitation

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I know that stored procedures in Oracle, can be coded in PL/SQL and Java.

May I know what are the advantage and disadvantages.

I am thinking taking certification for PL/SQL but I find that there are not much advantage of PL/SQL over Java SP.

2ndly I find that most of my developers are java pro-efficient, therefore is make more sense to develop SP on Java so they don't have to learn another language. (reduce development time and complication)

1) So should I stick to writing SP in Java?

Comment: SP is written in SQL, I believe!!!!

Comment: Stored Procedures in java ??? listening first time+

Comment: Developing Java Stored Procedures

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm

Comment: Java SP lets you use large library of existing Java code.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457896/java-stored-procedure-vs-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: If you're going to work with Oracle seriously, you'd want to learn PL/SQL to _read_ it, since it's widely used. OTOH PL/SQL is quite simple, it would take a weekend to get acquainted with it provided that you already know Java. Can't say anything about taking certification, though.

Comment: This will explain you about stored procedures 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072/when-should-you-use-java-stored-procedures-with-an-oracle-database-what-are!

Answer (score 4):

I've had some experience in writing Java Stored Procedures so I think I can definitely throw some light on this topic. I along with another lead developer had ported Oracle's Workflow - its Core Engine from PL/SQL to Java Stored Procedures, the WF Builder and Runtime Viewer from VC++ to Eclipse RCP.

**Why we chose Java SPs?**

- WF Engine could be moved out of Database onto a dedicated App Server in future.
- Workflows need to trigger and respond to Events. It's easily accomplished using JMS.
- Oracle also provided a JMS implementation called AQs (Advanced Queuing).

  - AQs are backed by database tables. So, it was fairly easy to query Event data for the UI.
  - Accessing AQs from Java stored procedures was quick and simple (no network overhead).

**Problems Faced**

- The JVM support wasn't up to date. We had to support Oracle 9 so wrote the engine to work on JDK 1.3 and it was a pain in the neck. Oracle 10 moved to JDK 1.4 and <s>I think things look a lot better now with JDK 1.6</s> I've come to know that support is still lagging behind with JDK 1.5 in Oracle 11.
- At times you do encounter situations where a Trigger or a Ref cursor i.e. some PL/SQL construct is the best fit. If you must have your application purely in Java you may have to go for a workaround. Otherwise, you could implement that functionality in PL/SQL and invoke it from Java. We didn't have this liberty.

Comment: unfortunately it's still version 1.5. So forget about flashy JEE stuff like JAXB, CDI, ... etc. Java stored procedures are useful for specific tasks only. (for example when you want to avoid round trips between DB and APP server). PL/SQL is really mighty tool for data manipulation.

Comment: @Ivan That's bad. So, not much has improved.. they're still running two JVM versions behind!

Answer (score 2):

In short:

Java over PL/SQL

- PL/SQL is a procedural language, Java is an object oriented one
- Java has many more 3rd party libraries
- Functionality of PL/SQL is limited, even with all additional libraries

PL/SQL over Java

- It is much easier for developing small and easy programs
- It has more natural constructs for data manipulation operations directly in tables
- Sometimes it's very difficult to deploy Java 3rd party libraries, even developed by Oracle and using manuals from their official web site (it can work in one version of DB, but doesn't in other)

But, in most cases PL/SQL is a much preferable way for developing stored procedures.
If you can't solve problem using PL/SQL then it's a reason to search solution outside of scope of stored procedures. First of all, OracleDB is a database, and it allows you to keep logic inside it as a bonus, but it's not an application server... Oracle has Java Applications Servers by the way.

But **sometimes** you need stored procedure/function, and the only way is to use fully functional languages/environments with extended functionality. And Java is the easiest way in such cases (for Oracle), much easier than developing in C/C++.